# Is it possible in Agda to define a new data type with meta-programming using reflection?

Tags: reflection, metaprogramming, agda

According to [Agda documentation](https://agda.readthedocs.io/en/v2.6.1.1/language/reflection.html), a new function can be declared and defined via reflection by applying `unquoteDecl` and `unquoteDef` to an appropriate tactic. Is this also possible for new data types and records? Or has Agda not implemented this feature yet?

Answer (score 3):

No, this feature has not yet been implemented. You can find some discussion on this issue at https://github.com/agda/agda/issues/3699.

EDIT: this feature will be added in Agda 2.6.3.

Comment: Thank you for the edit! I've also recently found out about this new feature on myself. However, the agda documentation for this feature does not seem to mention anything about records (such as coinductive records, which would be my main use case). Do you know whether this feature also supports record definitions?